# What shall be the optimal algorithm for going from source to to all vertices such that no vertex is visited twice?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dynamic-programming

Suppose you (let's say, A) and your colleagues(B and C) are to be picked up by a van from your office(O), which drops you guys to your respective homes. The distance from O to A (and vice-versa), O to B (and vice-versa), O to C (and vice-versa), A to B (and vice-versa), B to C (and vice-versa), and C to A (and vice-versa) is known. How will you calculate the shortest route taken by the van driver to drop all of you?

NOTE: Keep in mind that is not necessary that the distance from A to B and B to A is equal.

Comment: This is the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: This is the traveling salesman problem. What is it you want to know?

Comment: I might be wrong but generally, TSP uses an undirected graph. In this case, the graph is directed and has different weights (cost for A to B is different from cost for B to A). What should be the algorithm for this scenario?

Comment: @yash7696 The TSP has a symmetric and an asymmetric version.  The directed graph problem is the asymmetric version.  All variations are either NP-complete (can you do it for cost `x`) or NP-hard (what is the shortest route).  There is a tremendous literature but for a homework assignment I would assume that they just want a straightforward recursive search for the best solution.

Comment: The difference between NP-complete and NP-hard incidentally is, "If someone says that this is a solution, can you verify it in polynomial time?"  If they say, "Here is a route that costs < 100" you easily can.  If they say, "This is the best route possible" then where do you begin on verification?